# Beginner in desperate need: pastevalue() to create historical tab for investments

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste

Thank you very much in advance for your help, I'm new to coding but proficient with standard Excel functions. I would greatly appreciate any input on this project.

I want to create a Google spreadsheet that has 3 sheets. The first is a DATA sheet which lists stock tickers and provides live prices via Google finance {=googlefinance(VTI,price)}.

The second sheet is the MASTER sheet that aggregates all of the positions, including number of shares in stocks, quantity in fixed income instruments, quantity in bullion, etc. The prices used to calculate current market value of positions are drawn from the DATA sheet. All values are added together to create a total value cell, E57, that updates itself automatically from the google finance data throughout the trading day. This all works fine.

The final sheet is the HISTORY sheet. Here's what I want to do. I want cell E57 to copy to this sheet once a day at market close so I have a daily history of the aggregate portfolio. Each time the script copies and pastes the value to the HISTORY sheet, it needs to paste on the next available row in the same column. So far, I've written a script that successfully copies and pastes the value at a defined time interval (using Project Triggers), but it just keeps pasting over the previous value. How can I make it paste to each successive open cell and generate a list?

Also, I need all of this to work without me signing in or opening/activating the sheet. I want it to run completely autonomously, that's why I'm activating the sheet via openById instead of using the ActiveSheet code (I think that reasoning is correct, but not sure).

Here's the script I have:

```
function PasteValue() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Ao2pCtssx6TcdGpDWFpSXy1pUXA3MlAtSjZFVHlaZVE");

ss.getRange("MASTER!E57").copyTo(ss.getRange("HIST!C5"),{contentsOnly:true});

}
```

What do I do to improve?? Thank you!​

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests the name of the history sheet is HIST.

I think there are a few ways to do this:

Option 1:

Uses the [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow%28%29) method

```
function PasteValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Ao2pCtssx6TcdGpDWFpSXy1pUXA3MlAtSjZFVHlaZVE");
  var nextRow = ss.getSheetByName('HIST').getLastRow()+1;
  ss.getRange("MASTER!E57").copyTo(ss.getRange("HIST!C" + nextRow),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Note that option 1 will not work if you have a column of cells that contain formulas that have been copied down to the bottom of the sheet.

Option 2:

Loops through the cells in column C to find the first blank cell.

```
function PasteValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Ao2pCtssx6TcdGpDWFpSXy1pUXA3MlAtSjZFVHlaZVE");
  var values = ss.getRange("HIST!C:C").getValues();
  for (vari=0; i<values.length; ++i) {
    if (values[i][0] == "") {
      var nextRow = i+1;
      break;
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("MASTER!E57").copyTo(ss.getRange("HIST!C" + nextRow),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Option 2 should work as long as you have no blank cells in column C.

Option 3:
Use the [appendRow() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow%28Object%29)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, the first option works brilliantly.  The only problem is that when I close out of the sheet, the hourly trigger returns only "#N/A" into each successive cell; however, it works when I have the sheet open and an hour passes.  Is there something else I need to do in order for the worksheet to auto-refresh and auto-copy while the browser is closed?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it would work when your file is open and not work when the file is closed. It should make no difference. My hunch is that it may have something to do with the info received into MASTER!E57. Does that update when the spreadsheet is closed? However I have never used GoogleFinance so I'm sorry to say I can't help with that.